# Is MPC8260 microprocessor or microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor

**Microcontroller** has a CPU, in addition with a fixed amount of RAM, ROM and other peripherals all embedded on a single chip.

**Microprocessor** is an IC which has only the CPU inside them. They don’t have RAM, ROM, and other peripheral on the chip.

> These are the definitions for Microcontroller and Microprocessor I
>   found form googling. Is MPC8260 microprocessor or microcontroller?
>   When I saw the architecture of MPC8260, it has Timers, cache memory
>   and other peripherals on-chip. But on data sheet the title is MPC8260
>   Microprocessor. I am getting confused of this. MPC8260 is used for
>   specific purpose. In that point of view, we should call it a
>   microcontroller. But why are they calling it as microprocessor?

Comment: [Does this answer your question? Specifically the last line](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/1093/74840)

Comment: see also http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34083/is-arm-a-microprocessor-or-microcontroller/34086#34086

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference between a microprocessor and a microcontroller is that an MCU has sufficient built-in memory and I/O to work stand-alone, without requiring external interface and support chips (thus making it a 'controller' rather than a 'processor'). An MCU can trade bus signals for I/O pins, whereas a CPU needs the full bus to access external memory and I/O.

Of course some devices blur the line. MCUs may be 'ROMless', and CPUs can have a limited amount of built-in I/O. For example the HD64180 is a Z80 CPU combined with several support chips (MMU, DMA, Timer, UARTs) and optional internal ROM and RAM. However it is still described as a CPU because the full Z80 bus is available externally (so you could ignore the peripherals and use it as a bare CPU if you wanted).

Then there are chips which integrate a CPU or MCU with other specialized hardware. The MPC8260 is one of these. It is neither a microprocessor nor a microcontroller, but it *does* have both a microprocessor and a microcontroller embedded in it.

[MPC8260 PowerQUICC™ II Family Reference Manual](http://cache.freescale.com/files/product/doc/MPC8260UM.pdf)

> The PowerQUICC II™ is a versatile **communications processor** that
>   integrates on one chip a high-performance PowerPC™ RISC
>   microprocessor, a very flexible system integration unit, and many
>   communications peripheral controllers that can be used in a variety of
>   applications, particularly in communications and networking systems.